# Passing a Bundle with values from Fragment to a new Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, bundle

I'm trying to pass a bundle with an integer value from a fragment Activity page to a new activity page. However the integer doesn't seem to be passed on and thus its value is always at 0. What is causing this problem? Am I missing something?

This is the Fragment Activity:

```
public class TravelogueSEOPageFragment extends SherlockFragment {

    //method here that creates the bundle to be passed on to the new activity
    public void Map(View v){
        Intent offlineMapView = new Intent(v.getContext(), TOfflineMapView.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("id", travelogueID);
        offlineMapView.putExtras(b);
        startActivity(offlineMapView);
    }
}
```

This is the new Activity class:

```
public class TOfflineMapView extends Activity{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        int tID = b.getInt("id");

        ...//remove unnecessary codes
    }
}
```

So my tID is forever 0. Is this the wrong way to do it?

Comment: What is the value of `travelogueID`?

Comment: travelogueID will never be 0, it is a value that is being passed on from another activity as well so the value is not fixed.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see a blatant problem. Have you verified `travelogueID` in your debugger (or with the LogCat)? If you forgot to initialize `travelogueID` this makes perfect sense.

Comment: just try to pass static value for testing purpose and check your log what u are getting in next activity

Comment: Yup LogCat shows that the value is 0 every single time which shouldn't be.

Comment: what about its value in TravelogueSEOPageFragment fragment ?

Comment: For example, based on previous the previous activity and fragments, travelogueID will be 11783. Value in TravelogueSEOPageFragment is still 11783 but once passed to TOfflineMapView, it becomes 0.

Comment: Try adding `Log.v("Fragment", "travelogeID: " + travelogueID);` before `startActivity(offlineMapView);`. Do you see `"travelogeID: 11783"` or `"travelogeID: 0"`?

Comment: Ok now that's weird... Log.v is not shown in logcat at all, i changed to Log.e and nothing shows too... placed it even before the instantiation of the Intent object. Is that the reason why?

Comment: Are you getting any LogCat statements from your app? If yes, then do you start this same Activity anywhere else? (Use `@Sam` to reply to a specific user. Otherwise I might forget to check for responses... The author of the question or answer gets an automatic notification that's why I don't have to use `@lyk` here.)

Comment: @Sam yes I am getting other LogCat statements, that's why I'm very surprised none of the Log.v/e statements are showing that I inserted in the Map(View v) method

Comment: If the debugger shows `travelogueID` in `Map(View)` is anything other than 0, I'm at a loss...

Comment: @Sam sorry I might have phrased it wrongly. it's not that it displays anything other than 0... it's that NONE of the Log.e or Log.v statments I've placed in Map(View v) is being displayed. Not even a Log.e("test","Test") that was placed before Intent offlineMapView = new Intent(v.getContext(), TOfflineMapView.class);

Comment: Well the debugger and LogCat are different. Have you confirmed with the debugger that you are even in `Map(View)`? As for the LogCat, if you are not accidentally filtering out these message in the LogCat window, you can reset the ADB and make sure your are listing to the correct device in the Device window.